# Is this Ok for UK Business Visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am Owner Sole Proprietor of my Company. I am going to apply business visa for UK. I want to ask from experts that am i filling correct the form?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few things occur to me

- "Sole Proprietor" is too vague. I believe it is expected that you indicate the actual nature of your work or business - carpenter, architect, mobile phone salesman, consulting surgeon etc.
- Where they ask why your employer or company is helping to pay for your visit, I suspect they want the business purpose of the visit - they probably want to know who will you be visiting and what specific business activities will you be carrying out. For example "My company has a contract with BAE Midwich to provide 3 days training of remote-drone pilots in the use of the Foomatic 3000 battlefield visualisation system." or "I have a series of meetings arranged with Tyrell Corp, CHOAM, Acme Industries and Massive Dynamics in order to select a primary UK distributor for the range of Turbo-Encabulators manufactured by my company".

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I understand I should brief about my visit with detail what's the reason i am going.
I need to ask as a proprietor, is it well my company pay me? or should I select " Paying for your trip " = NO ? because as proprietor we can pay myself.